# jQuery Validate Address - Google Places API

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-validate, google-places-api

I have a simple form where the user enters an address.

Before the form is submitted I perform a TextSearch using the Places Api and put this data into a hidden input field in the form, and then submit it.

**I want to use jQuery Validate to the validate the form, but I dont know how to get the Places data together with it.**

I think I have to use the submitHandler with Validate, but im not sure how to put my code in here:

```
$("#myform").validate({
 submitHandler: function(form) {
   form.submit();
 }
});
```

Here is my code I have without the Validate plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Maps Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
            #map_canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var service;
            var infowindow;
            var service;
            var validated = false;

            function initialize() {
                var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        center: pyrmont,
                        zoom: 15
                    });

                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            }

            function textsearchcallback(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    var place = results[0];
                    var request = {
                        reference: place.reference
                    };
                    service.getDetails(request, getdetailscallback);
                } else {
                    alert("ERROR: NO RESULTS FOUND!");
                }
            }

            function getdetailscallback(place, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    $("#placeinfo").val(JSON.stringify(place));
                    validated = true;
                    $("#search-form").submit();
                    validated = false;
                    $("#placeinfo").val("");
                } else {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            }

            function validateForm() {
                var searchfield = $("#search-field").val();
                if (searchfield == null || searchfield == "") {
                    alert("Please enter address");
                    return false;
                }
                if (validated) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    var request = {
                        query: searchfield
                    };
                    service.textSearch(request, textsearchcallback);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initialize()">
        <form id="search-form" name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Address, Airport or Postcode..." id="search-field" size="50" type="text"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="placeinfo" id="placeinfo">
            <input type="SUBMIT" value="Search" /><br>
        </form>

        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a Fiddle with the working code: [http://jsfiddle.net/robertdodd/txqnL/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/Homeliss/txqnL/26/)

Comment: Please explain what _"get the Places data together with it"_ is supposed to mean.  What exactly are the parameters for the data are you trying to validate?

Comment: I think your project is too large to expect somebody else to do all the work for you, and much of the HTML referenced in your JS is missing.  I suggest that you use my answer below to get started, use jsFiddle to construct working demos, and then post a new question here on SO whenever you get stuck.  Please make them as specific and concise as possible.  See http://sscce.org for tips.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, and sorry for the messy question. Ive since seen some other questions with fiddle demos and they make it much easier to help!

Comment: See the edit on my answer that points out a mistake in the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Option 1 - Client side validation**

This method is messy and a bit of a hack, I DO NOT recommended this unless you have no other way. I recommend using [another validation library](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/02/40-stand-alone-javascript-libraries-for-specific-purposes/) or writing your own, which is what I plan to do myself.

**Simple demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/robertdodd/txqnL/27/

Heres step by step what happens:

1. User clicks submit
2. Form is validated by jQuery
3. In the submit handler I prevent the form from submitting and look up the address with google
4. When google returns I fill the hidden input and set `validated = true`
5. I then resubmit the form, and this time it submits because `validated == true`

## **Option 2 - Server side validation:**

The other option is server side validation, which I recommend as a backup anyway. Here is how to use it with the validate plugin.

1. Use [remote validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) to get a response from server
2. Use [dataFilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to retrieve the Maps info from the response, put it into hidden input, then change response by returning either '"true"' or '"error message"' because remote validation requires a certain string ([read here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote))

Heres my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  function initialize() {
    $("#search-form").validate({
      rules: {
        searchfield: {
          required: true,
          remote: {
            url: "/validate",
            type: "get",
            dataFilter: function(data) {
              var json = JSON.parse(data);
              var placename = json.placename;
              $('#placename').val(placename);
              return '"' + json.result + '"';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
  
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <form id="search-form" >
      <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter a location" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" type="text" /><br/>
      <input type="hidden" name="placename" id="placename" />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" /><br/>
    </form>
    <div id="successmessage"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to integrate jQuery Validation in place of your own manual validation.  Yes, you would call your functions from within the plugin's `submitHandler`, but there is too much code missing from your OP for a working demo of your Maps functions.

This is something like what you'd need to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your rules and options,
        ignore: [], // this option is required if you need to validate hidden inputs
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            // your functions here
            form.submit(); // to submit the form when you're ready
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you need to use ajax to submit the form without a page redirect...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your rules and options,
        ignore: [], // this option is required if you need to validate hidden inputs
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            // ajax functions here
            return false; // to block the normal form submit since you just did it with ajax
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

You will also need to remove the `onsubmit` event handler from your HTML since that's already built into the jQuery Validate plugin.

```
<form id="search-form" name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

would become...

```
<form id="search-form" name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
```

**Simplified Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/wbdvc/

---

**EDIT:**

Regarding the [jsFiddle demo in the OP's edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Homeliss/txqnL/26/):

The following `if/then` conditional will never work properly.  [By definition, the `submitHandler` is the callback for a **valid** form](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).  In other words, the **only** time the `submitHandler` function will run is *after* the form has already tested "valid" and just before the actual form `submit`.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    if (validated) { 
        // address is validated and hidden input filled, so submit the form
        alert('valid form submitted');
        validated = false;
    } else { 
        // address is not validated yet, look up on Google Maps
        var request = {
            query: $("#searchfield").val()
        };
        service.textSearch(request, textsearchcallback);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Instead of placing that logic inside of `submitHandler`, you could place it within `addMethod`...

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

This creates a new rule that you would use like any other predefined Validate plugin rule.

Comment: Only saw your edit after posting my answer, I'll check it out and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: When i use addMethod, the function gets called whenever the text box is changed and loses focus. That means my callback ends up calling form.submit, before the form is submitted. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Homeliss/hX4FN/5/

Comment: @Homeliss,  Now I see why you originally put `validated` inside the `submitHandler`.  I know a lot about the plugin, but I'm not as familiar with the Google Maps code.  Is this one better?  http://jsfiddle.net/hX4FN/6/

Comment: @Homeliss, the idea here is to contain as much of the code within the custom method and/or the `submitHandler`.  We shouldn't need the `validate` flag at all if we can figure this out properly.  And the `form.submit()` should be _inside_ the `submitHandler` and no-place else.

Comment: The only way I can see is to use the [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) method, but that wont work because you cant perform http Maps requests from JavaScript due to it being cross-domain, you have to use their JavaScript library.

Comment: @Homeliss,  It's still all JavaScript, so there should be a way.  I wish I could be more specifically helpful.  If I figure something clever out, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with using `form.submit` outside of `submitHandler`? I am using `$("#search-form").submit()` at the moment, which is different, but I was going to change it to `form.submit()` before you mentioned it.

Comment: @Homeliss, `form.submit()` is the shorthand used _within_ the `submitHandler`. `$("#search-form").submit()` is the same.  I say "don't do it outside of `submitHandler`" because the `submitHandler` is what you've put in charge of the `submit` click event when you use the Validate plugin.  I think it's verbose and unreliable to use several `submit` click handlers at once.

Comment: thanks for all your help! I figured out how to do it server-side with `remote`. I think I need a different solution to Validate for client-side in my case though, I can write something up later. I really appreciate your time helping me!